# disable autocomplete input text in login form

Tags: php, jquery, css

```
<input name="login" type="text" autocomplete="off" required>

<input name="password" type="password" required autocomplete="off">
```

and this is my js code for disable autocomplete

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(':input').live('focus',function(){
            $(this).attr('autocomplete', 'off');
        });
        $('form').attr('autocomplete','off');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Comment: You shouldn't have the `:` in your `('input')` selector

Comment: `$('input').live('focus',function(){`

Comment: What if you put value="" does that make a difference?

Comment: Sorry for the maybe stupid question, but why the JS-part? Your inputs already have `autocomplete="off"`, why set it again in JS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `:` in your input selector. The below modification should help:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input').on('click', function(){
            $(this).attr('autocomplete', 'off');
        });
    });
</script>
```

you can also use many other predefined functions like `onkeyup`, `onkeydown` etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can disable this with simple html

put 2 false inputs before your input

```
<input class="hidden" type="text" style="display: none!important; visibility: hidden!important;" ></input>
<input class="hidden" type="password" style="display: none!important; visibility: hidden!important;" ></input>
```